# How to find item in wpf listview after second right-click?

Tags: wpf, listview, right-click, wpf-listview

Certainly something I don't understand but I hope you could help me.

I have a wpf list view defined like this :

```
<ListView x:Name="listviewPlugins" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemContainerStylePlugin}" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderBrush="White" 
                                      AllowDrop="True" Drop="listviewPlugins_Drop" DragEnter="listviewPlugins_DragEnter"
                                      PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="listviewPlugins_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ContextMenuOpening="listviewPlugins_ContextMenuOpening"
                                      MouseMove="listviewPlugins_MouseMove"
                                      KeyDown="listviewPlugins_KeyDown" >
                                <ListView.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource ContextMenus}" x:Name="PluginContextMenu" StaysOpen="False">
                                        <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}" x:Name="MenuConfigurePlugin" Header="{DynamicResource configurePlugin}" Click="MenuConfigurePlugin_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Foreground="Gray" Kind="Pencil" LayoutTransform="{StaticResource ContextMenuIconScaleTransform}"/>
                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <Separator Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuSeparator}"></Separator>
                                        <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}" x:Name="MenuDuplicatePlugin" Header="{DynamicResource duplicatePlugin}" Click="MenuDuplicatePlugin_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Foreground="Gray" Kind="ContentCopy" LayoutTransform="{StaticResource ContextMenuIconScaleTransform}"/>
                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                        <Separator Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuSeparator}"></Separator>
                                        <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}" x:Name="MenuRemovePlugin" Header="{DynamicResource deletePlugin}" Click="MenuRemovePlugin_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                <materialDesign:PackIcon Foreground="Gray" Kind="ToyBrickRemoveOutline"  LayoutTransform="{StaticResource ContextMenuIconScaleTransform}"/>
                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                        </MenuItem>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </ListView.ContextMenu>
                                <ListView.View>
                                    <GridView x:Name="listviewPluginsColumns" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle}">
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="{DynamicResource PluginName}" Width="220" >
                                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel Height="21" Margin="0"  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="20" Height="20"></Image>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>                                                            
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn>
                                        <GridViewColumn  Header="{DynamicResource PluginDescription}" Width="250" >
                                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                                    <StackPanel Height="21" Margin="0"  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserDescription}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn>
                                    </GridView>
                                </ListView.View>
                            </ListView>
```

If I right-click on one item thus the menu opens thus no problem.

But if I click on another item while the menu is open then the menu closes and opens again but the selected item is still the previously selected item.
How can I make sure that the selected item is the one under the mouse?

I tried this code in PreviewMouseRightButtonDown but I can't get either ListViewItem or Item to select it:

```
var hit = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(listviewPlugins,Mouse.GetPosition(listviewPlugins)).VisualHit)
```

Thank you for your help.

Update :

```
private void MenuRemovePlugin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveSelectedPlugin();
        return;

    }

private void RemoveSelectedPlugin()
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(cultureHelper.GetCultureString("deletePluginConfirmationContent"), cultureHelper.GetCultureString("deletePluginConfirmationTitle"), MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            PluginInterface.Plugin source = (PluginInterface.Plugin)listviewPlugins.SelectedItem;
            
            Configuration.Data.CfgJob job = (Configuration.Data.CfgJob)listviewJobs.SelectedItems[0];
            job.RemovePlugin(source);
            listviewPlugins.ItemsSource = null;
            listviewPlugins.ItemsSource = job.Plugins;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Right-clicking is not supposed to select an item, is it?

Comment: Well, when I right-click on the item with index 2 for example thus the menu opens and I can remove (or do something else) this item. But when I right-click on the item with index 1 after right-clicking on item of index 2 thus the menu opens but item with index 2 is removed. Thus, there is a selection on the first right-click.

Comment: The item is removed form the listview

Comment: Where do you want to get a reference to which item?

Comment: I want to remove the item on which I did the right-click by the click on contextMenu (MenuRemovePlugin_Click)

Answer (score 0):

You could move the `ContextMenu` from the `ListView` control itself to the `ListViewItem` container:

```
<ListView x:Name="listviewPlugins">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu">
            ...
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource contextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="listviewPluginsColumns" ... />
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

...and then easily get a reference to the parent `ListViewItem` or its `DataContext` in the event handler:

```
private void MenuRemovePlugin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
    ContextMenu contextMenu = menuItem.Parent as ContextMenu;
    if (contextMenu != null)
    {
        ListViewItem listViewItem = contextMenu.PlacementTarget as ListViewItem;
        if (listViewItem != null)
        {
            object data = listViewItem.DataContext;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I move the ContexMenu as you suggested, I can't use PluginContextMenu and MenuItems in the events of the listView (for example to disable or enable context menu

Comment: What do you mean? The event handler is still defined in the same place.